# managing focus with multiple inputs within a popover in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, focus

I am using ChakraUI to implement a popover that contains 2 number inputs.  My problem is that I can't get the focus to remain on the second number input, it always pops back to the first.  i've tried using refs and setting focus in useEffect but this didn't solve anything..  a hopefully sufficient code extract can be found below:

codepen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-react-hook-form-forked-w8dqy6?file=/src/index.js

```
    function ListNewItem() {

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        <Popover
            returnFocusOnClose={false}
            isOpen={show_new_listing}
            onClose={() => setShowNewListing(false)}
            placement='bottom'
            closeOnBlur={false}
            
        >
            <PopoverTrigger>
                <Box as='button'  onClick={() => setShowNewListing(true)}>
                    <Text>List New Item</Text>
                </Box>
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent backgroundColor={"black"} >
                <div className="font-face-sfpb" color="white">
                    <PopoverHeader>Enter Listing Details</PopoverHeader>
                </div>
                <PopoverArrow />
                <PopoverCloseButton/>
                <PopoverBody>
                    <FocusLock returnFocus persistentFocus={false}>
                    <div className="font-face-sfpb">    
                        <VStack align="center">
                            <HStack width="80%" align={"left"} >     
                                <Box width="50%"><Text>Item:</Text></Box>   
                                <Box width="50%">
                                <Text>Test Item</Text>
                                </Box>
                            </HStack>     
                            <HStack width="80%" align={"left"} >     
                                <Box width="50%"><Text>Price:</Text></Box>   
                                <Box width="50%">
                                    <NumberInput 
                                        id="desired_price"
                                        ref={priceRef}
                                        onChange={(valueString) => {setListPrice(checkParseInt(valueString)); console.log(valueString); console.log(priceRef.current)}}
                                        value={list_price}>
                                        
                                        
                                        <NumberInputField
                                        autoFocus={false}
                                        />
                                    </NumberInput>
                                </Box>
                            </HStack>        
                            <HStack width="80%" align={"left"} >         
                                <Box width="50%"><Text>Quantity:</Text></Box>   
                                <Box width="50%">
                                    <NumberInput 
                                        id="desired_quantity"
                                        ref={quantityRef}
                                        onChange={(valueString) => {setListQuantity(checkParseInt(valueString)); console.log(quantityRef.current)}}
                                        value={list_quantity >= 0 ? list_quantity.toString() : ""}
                                        >
                                        
                                        
                                        <NumberInputField
                                        autoFocus={false}
                                        />
                                    </NumberInput>
                                </Box>
                            </HStack>    
                           
        
                            <Box as='button' onClick={ListItemOnMarketplace}>
                                <Text>LIST</Text>
                            </Box>
                                
                            
                            
                        </VStack>
                        </div>    
                    </FocusLock>
                </PopoverBody>
            </PopoverContent>
        </Popover>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

priceRef and quantityRef are defined as follows:

```
const priceRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
const quantityRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

If you need anything else provided let me know.. i've tried having useEffects such as :

```
useEffect(() => 
{
    quantityRef.current?.focus();
    
}, [list_quantity]);
```

But i can't get the focus to remain with the input i'm currently using.

Many thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to maintain focus on the second NumberInputField, but the provided code doesn't set the focus on the second input when it's rendered. Instead, you can use the onBlur event of the NumberInput component to return the focus to the second input when it loses focus.

Here's a modified version of your code that should maintain focus on the second NumberInputField:

```
function ListNewItem() {
    // ...

    const handleQuantityInputBlur = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            quantityRef.current?.focus();
        }, 0);
    };

    return (
        // ...
        <HStack width="80%" align={"left"} >
            <Box width="50%"><Text>Quantity:</Text></Box>
            <Box width="50%">
                <NumberInput
                    id="desired_quantity"
                    ref={quantityRef}
                    onBlur={handleQuantityInputBlur}
                    onChange={(valueString) => {setListQuantity(checkParseInt(valueString)); console.log(quantityRef.current)}}
                    value={list_quantity >= 0 ? list_quantity.toString() : ""}
                >
                    <NumberInputField autoFocus={false} />
                </NumberInput>
            </Box>
        </HStack>
        // ...
    );
}
```

This code adds an onBlur event to the NumberInput component that calls the handleQuantityInputBlur function. This function sets a timeout with a delay of 0ms, which ensures that the focus returns to the second input after the current event loop is finished.

This should maintain the focus on the second NumberInputField when you interact with it.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to help, however i found a smoking gun.. if I move all the code in the function that creates the popover into the main function it all works.. i've created a codepen that recreates the issue